# How can I make my executable considered trustworthy by Windows and common Antivirus applications?

Tags: digital-signature, antivirus

I have developed a certain portable program. I have posted it to my website, and made it available for downloading. However, whenever I download that executable from my website, and try to open it, first I get the warning from Windows, "The publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software?", and even if I proceed, my antivirus (Avast) puts it into a DeepScreen, analyzing it for a considerable time before it realizes it is safe.

My question is, what should I do so that the users of my program wouldn't have to deal with these inconveniences? How do I make my program "verified" by Windows and all the numerous antiviruses that are out there?

I apologize if a similar question was asked before, but after a considerable amount of googling, I was unable to find a solution. Most people give information on how to add exclusions for an executable for specific antiviruses on specific computers, but that won't help the people who will use my program. what I want to do here is prevent the problem in the first place. Any advice?

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is *code signing*.

Comment: Thank you, Ken, but as far as I'm searching, most sites say I will have to purchase CA certificate, which is insanely expensive. Is there a way to sign my executable for free?

Comment: Not that Windows and AV vendors will consider safe. For that, you need to purchase an actual valid code signing certificate from an authority that is widely accepted. If Windows would accept just any old certificate, then any malware could use a generic one and get past the checks. Think about it - you're asking Windows and AV vendors to know your product is safe. How else would they do it?

Comment: So what are my options? There is no way in hell I can afford the prices I'm seeing for these certificates. Not by a long shot. EDIT: Answering your question... Well, WIndows and AV vendors could know by testing my executable (which they probably have to do anyway), and sign it if it's safe? I don't really see why it has to be so goddamn expensive.

Comment: What part isn't clear? Your option is to buy a valid code signing certificate to get approved as being safe, or stay the way you are now. I have nothing to do with that, and neither does anyone else here. If you want to be accepted by the OS as safe, buy the certificate and pass through the validation steps. There is work done by the certificate issuers to validate your identity and confirm your information, and they charge for it. Otherwise, keep doing what you're doing and don't try to sell or distribute your software. MS can't do that - there are too many apps. Who pays them to do it?

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information. I suppose I will keep it unsigned, and inform my customers to ignore these warnings when they download my program.

Comment: Besides, pretty much every CA vendor I found requires you to have a confirmed business for validation. What if I were just making freeware apps for Windows for no profit? Isn't it an overkill to have to establish a business just to validate them?

Answer (score 1):

1. Code-signing: unsigned or incorrectly signed software is a big red-flag
2. Time: New executables are always regarded as more dangerous, if the AV has seen the same file before on many systems, it's more likely to be safe. Signing might allow some transfer of this reputation to new executables.
3. Reputation: Once you are signing executables the vendors can treat all those signed by you in a similar manner.

As a fall-back AV vendors generally have a mechanism for submitting files as false-positives, which might prevent them being detected as malware, and allow short-cutting of lengthy scanning procedures.

I haven't ever bought a code-signing cert, but Comodo seems to be the cheapest at £75 for a year.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Douglas. As I've googled this further, I realized that code signing is an extremely expensive service, and also requires one to have a registered company. Every CA vendor I looked up, asks for a company name. But what if I am a private individual with no company/business, and only making small, cheap, one-time sales? How do I get a certificate without breaking a hole in my pocket?